# How to have a RestTemplate encode all characters with UriComponents and EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want my REST client, using Spring Web's `RestTemplate`, to %-encode all special characters in URL parameters, not only illegal characters. [Spring Web's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#web-uri-encoding) states that the encoding method can be changed by configuring the `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` used by `RestTemplate` with `setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY)`:

```
String baseUrl = "http://example.com";
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(baseUrl)
factory.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(factory);
```

this [should](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.html) "apply [UriUtils.encode(String, Charset)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html#encode-java.lang.String-java.nio.charset.Charset-) to each URI variable value" which in turn will "encode all characters that are either illegal, or have any reserved meaning, anywhere within a URI, as defined in RFC 3986".

I wrote the following test case to try and demonstrate that changing to `EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY` does not have the desired effect. (executing it with dependencies `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.3.RELEASE`, `org.springframework:spring-web:5.0.7.RELEASE`, `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.0.3.RELEASE`)

```
package com.example.demo.encoding;

import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.RestClientTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(DemoClient.class)
public class EncodingTest {
  @Autowired private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
  @Autowired private DemoClient client;

  @Test
  public void encodeAllCharactersInParameter() {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo(encodedQueryUrl("https://host", "+:/")))
      .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
      .andRespond(withSuccess());
    client.request("https://host", "+:/");
    mockServer.verify();
  }

  private String encodedQueryUrl(final String baseUrl, final String parameter) {
    return String.format("%s?parameter=%s", baseUrl,
      UriUtils.encode(parameter, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
}

@Component
class DemoClient {
  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public DemoClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
    factory.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
    restTemplateBuilder.uriTemplateHandler(factory);
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
  }

  public Object request(final String url, final String parameter) {
    UriComponents queryUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
      .queryParam("parameter", parameter).build().encode();
    return restTemplate.getForObject(queryUrl.toUri(), Object.class);
  }
}
```

This test fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: Request URI expected:<https://host?parameter=%2B%3A%2F> but was:<https://host?parameter=+:/>`. So what am I doing wrong? Is it a bug in Spring Framework or does `MockRestServiceServer` decode URLs before verifying expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in the example:

One, the request method prepares and encodes a `java.net.URI` externally, so the `RestTemplate` is not the one preparing it. You need to pass a URI template with a URI variable in it, so that the `RestTemplate` has a chance to prepare the `URI` and do the encoding. For example:

```
public Object request(final String url, final String parameter) {
    String urlString = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParam("parameter", "{param}")
            .build()
            .toUriString();
    return restTemplate.getForObject(urlString, Object.class, parameter);
}
```

Or simply have request take the URI template string:

```
public Object request(final String url) {
    return restTemplate.getForObject(url, Object.class, parameter);
}

// then invoke like this...
request("https://host?parameter={param}");
```

Two, the `RestTemplateBuilder#uriTemplateHandler` returns a new instance, so you need to use that for the configuration change to take effect:

```
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
factory.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
restTemplateBuilder = restTemplateBuilder.uriTemplateHandler(factory); // <<<< see here
this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
```

It works as expected with the above changes.

Note that https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17039 will make it easier to also achieve the same effect using UriComponentsBuilder, so check for updates there.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected example:

```
package com.example.demo.encoding;

import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.method;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.client.response.MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.RestClientTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(DemoClient.class)
public class EncodingTest {
  @Autowired private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
  @Autowired private DemoClient client;

  @Test
  public void encodeAllCharactersInParameter() {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo(encodedQueryUrl("https://host", "+:/")))
      .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
      .andRespond(withSuccess());
    client.request("https://host", "+:/");
    mockServer.verify();
  }

  private String encodedQueryUrl(final String baseUrl, final String parameter) {
    return String.format("%s?parameter=%s", baseUrl,
      UriUtils.encode(parameter, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
}

@Component
class DemoClient {
  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public DemoClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
    factory.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.uriTemplateHandler(factory).build();
  }

  public Object request(final String url, final String parameter) {
    String urlString = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
      .queryParam("parameter", "{param}").build().toUriString();
    return restTemplate.getForObject(urlString, Object.class, parameter);
  }
}
```